# custom profile fields in jomsocial

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, jomsocial

I am looking for the nice extension for creating custom profile fields from front end in jomsocial.Is there any third party extension to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there's a backend functionality for that. you can also buy the JSPT component that does from the backend, not frontend though.